# Why i am getting this error"TypeError: store.getState is not a function. (In 'store.getState()', 'store.getState' is undefined)"

Tags: react-native

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { profileReducer } from './Reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  Reducer: profileReducer
});

const initialState = {};

const middleWare = [thunk];

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleWare));

  return { store };
};
```

// Why i am getting this error "TypeError: store.getState is not a function. (In 'store.getState()', 'store.getState' is undefined)" Please help me i am new for redux

Comment: where are you calling this default exported store?  does the error log point to a component?

Comment: I don't think you are exporting store correctly. Is there a reason that you need to wrap your store in an arrow function ?
I would recommend simply export the store variable and not the arrow function

Answer (score 0):

Inside app.js:

```
import store from 'your-file-name'
....
<Provider store={store()}>
....
</Provider>
```

I think you are directly using store there, instead call it like so: store()